# How do I solve this temporary platform puzzle?

Tags: cross-code

After some searching and sleuthing, I finally managed to track down the location of the "Cursed Temple", wherein lies some kind of boss-level bone shark. Before I can fight him, though, I need to solve two puzzles. I solved the one on the right side of the temple, which simply involved some precise timing. The puzzle on the left is stumping me though. On its face, it seems easy, since all you appear to need to do is jump quickly across temporary platforms to reach the end of chamber. However, I can't reach the end without running out of time. See this image for the challenge:

[image: My attempts at running through this challenge]

As you can see, I waste very little time starting the platform course, but I still fall short. I have no idea how to speed myself up, because as far as I know there's no armor that gives you flat movement speed. So how do I complete this challenge?

(I have both the Heat and Cold elementals, if that's important.)

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer, as I've never played this game, but when you're on that long middle platform, could you shoot the pinwheel again?

Comment: @Pyritie Actually that's a good idea, I can probably richochet the ball back. The fact that the course is timed made me think I have to do the whole thing in one go, but now that I look at it, I guess there's no absolute reason that's true. I'll test when I get home from work.

Comment: @Pyritie Yep, that did it. Seems pretty obvious in hindsight, considering the whole game is about ricocheting your projectiles... but I guess I needed a fresh pair of eyes! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jump to the long stationary platform in the middle, then ricochet the ball back to the pinwheel to start the timer again.